# How to restore default settings for charts in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get a plot, but I have

[image]

So, how can I improve this?

Comment: Does it persist after you restart you R-session?

Comment: what if you do `par()` before you launch your plot?

Comment: yes, man you are the god!

Comment: its for Heroka lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I know that it works well, I post it as a solution. Just reset all parameters with:

```
par()
plot(yourplot)
```